# Tell me Concurrent Transaction problems and their solutions?

Tags: database, concurrency, transactions

Reference to the database I am looking for concurrent transaction problems and their solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for "transaction isolation level" and choose one of the many production documentation (for example PostgreSQL https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/transaction-iso.html.).

Main Concurrent transactions issues are:

1. Dirty Read
2. Nonrepeatable Read
3. Phantom Read
4. Serialization Anomaly